# React native - Issue on Android

Tags: react-native, react-native-reanimated, react-native-gesture-handler, moti

The issue started when I installed Moti, reanimated and gesture-handler. The problem only happens on my Android emulator. When I run the app on my iPhone, I don't have any issues. I don't get any errors in the console, just the emulator. Below is the code.

[Link to error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s3a9v.png)

```
import { View, ScrollView } from "react-native";
import * as React from "react";
import {
  Avatar,
  Button,
  Card,
  Text,
  SegmentedButtons,
  Portal,
  Dialog,
  ActivityIndicator,
  HelperText,
} from "react-native-paper";
import Slider from "@react-native-community/slider";
import { MotiView } from "moti";

const Generator = () => {
  const [amount, setAmount] = React.useState(0);
  const [mint, setMint] = React.useState(0);
  const [customMint, setCustomMint] = React.useState(5);
  const [type, setType] = React.useState([]);
  const [nicotine, setNicotine] = React.useState("");
  const [visible, setVisible] = React.useState(false);
  const [genVisible, setGenVisible] = React.useState(false);
  const hideDialog = () => setVisible(false);

  function sleep(ms) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
  }

  const genMix = async () => {
    setVisible(false);
    setGenVisible(true);
    await sleep(3500);
    setGenVisible(false);
  };

  return (
    <ScrollView>
      <View style={{ paddingVertical: 0 }}>
        <Card
          mode="contained"
          style={{ backgroundColor: "#F4F4F4", paddingBottom: 10 }}
          theme={{ roundness: 0 }}
        >
          <Card.Title
            title="Mix Generator"
            left={(props) => <Avatar.Icon {...props} icon="chip" />}
          />
          <Card.Content>
            <MotiView
              from={{ opacity: 0, scale: 0.5, translateY: 30 }}
              animate={{ opacity: 1, scale: 1, translateY: 0 }}
              transition={{ type: "spring" }}
            >
              <Text variant="titleMedium" style={{ marginBottom: 6 }}>
                How many flavors woud you like to mix?
              </Text>
              <SegmentedButtons
                theme={{ roundness: 1 }}
                value={amount}
                onValueChange={setAmount}
                buttons={[
                  {
                    value: "2",
                    label: "2",
                  },
                  {
                    value: "3",
                    label: "3",
                  },
                  {
                    value: "4",
                    label: "4",
                  },
                  { value: "5", label: "5" },
                ]}
              />
            </MotiView>
            {amount !== 0 && (
              <MotiView
                from={{ opacity: 0, scale: 0.5, translateY: 30 }}
                animate={{ opacity: 1, scale: 1, translateY: 0 }}
                transition={{ type: "spring" }}
              >
                <Text variant="titleMedium" style={{ marginVertical: 6 }}>
                  Would you like to add mint?
                </Text>
                <SegmentedButtons
                  theme={{ roundness: 1 }}
                  value={mint}
                  onValueChange={setMint}
                  buttons={[
                    {
                      value: "nomint",
                      label: "No mint",
                    },
                    {
                      value: "10",
                      label: "10%",
                    },
                    {
                      value: "20",
                      label: "20%",
                    },
                    { value: "custom", label: "Custom" },
                  ]}
                />
              </MotiView>
            )}
            {mint === "custom" && (
              <MotiView
                style={{ padding: 10 }}
                from={{ opacity: 0, scale: 0.5, translateY: 30 }}
                animate={{ opacity: 1, scale: 1, translateY: 0 }}
                transition={{ type: "spring" }}
              >
                <HelperText
                  type="info"
                  style={{
                    fontSize: 17,
                    color: "#424242",
                    marginTop: 12,
                    textAlign: "center",
                  }}
                >
                  Mint amount: {customMint}%
                </HelperText>
                <Slider
                  style={{
                    height: 40,
                    alignItems: "center",
                    marginVertical: 6,
                  }}
                  lowerLimit={0.05}
                  step={0.05}
                  minimumValue={0.05}
                  maximumValue={0.8}
                  minimumTrackTintColor="#663399"
                  maximumTrackTintColor="#CCCCCC"
                  thumbTintColor="#663399"
                  value={0.05}
                  onValueChange={(value) =>
                    setCustomMint(parseInt(value * 100))
                  }
                />
                <Button
                  theme={{ roundness: 1 }}
                  icon="leaf-circle"
                  mode="elevated"
                  onPress={() => setMint(customMint)}
                  style={{ marginHorizontal: 20 }}
                >
                  Set
                </Button>
              </MotiView>
            )}
            {mint !== 0 && (
              <MotiView
                from={{ opacity: 0, scale: 0.5, translateY: 30 }}
                animate={{ opacity: 1, scale: 1, translateY: 0 }}
                transition={{ type: "spring" }}
              >
                <Text variant="titleMedium" style={{ marginVertical: 6 }}>
                  What flavor profile would you like?
                </Text>
                <SegmentedButtons
                  multiSelect
                  theme={{ roundness: 1 }}
                  value={type}
                  onValueChange={setType}
                  buttons={[
                    {
                      value: "fruity",
                      label: "Fruit",
                    },
                    {
                      value: "citrus",
                      label: "Citrus",
                    },
                    {
                      value: "desert",
                      label: "Desert",
                    },
                    { value: "floral", label: "Floral" },
                  ]}
                />
                {type.length !== 2 && (
                  <HelperText
                    type="info"
                    style={{
                      fontSize: 15,
                      color: "#787878",
                      marginTop: 6,
                      textAlign: "center",
                    }}
                  >
                    Select up to 2
                  </HelperText>
                )}
              </MotiView>
            )}
            {type.length !== 0 && (
              <MotiView
                from={{ opacity: 0, scale: 0.5, translateY: 30 }}
                animate={{ opacity: 1, scale: 1, translateY: 0 }}
                transition={{ type: "spring" }}
              >
                <Text variant="titleMedium" style={{ marginVertical: 6 }}>
                  Nicotine level?
                </Text>
                <SegmentedButtons
                  theme={{ roundness: 1 }}
                  value={nicotine}
                  onValueChange={setNicotine}
                  buttons={[
                    {
                      value: "low",
                      label: "Low",
                    },
                    {
                      value: "medium",
                      label: "Medium",
                    },
                    {
                      value: "high",
                      label: "High",
                    },
                  ]}
                />
              </MotiView>
            )}
          </Card.Content>
          {nicotine !== "" && (
            <MotiView 
            style={{ alignItems: "center" }}
            from={{ opacity: 0, scale: 0.5, translateY: 30 }}
            animate={{ opacity: 1, scale: 1, translateY: 0 }}
            transition={{ type: 'spring' }}
            >
              <Button
                mode="contained"
                icon="fire"
                theme={{ roundness: 0 }}
                style={{ marginTop: 50, marginBottom: 10, width: "70%" }}
                onPress={() => setVisible(true)}
              >
                Generate Mix
              </Button>
            </MotiView>
          )}
          <Portal>
            <Dialog
              visible={visible}
              onDismiss={hideDialog}
              theme={{ roundness: 2 }}
            >
              <Dialog.Icon icon="leaf" />
              <Dialog.Title style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>
                Mix Overview
              </Dialog.Title>
              <Dialog.Content>
                <Text variant="bodyLarge">Amount of Flavors: {amount}</Text>
                <Text variant="bodyLarge">Mint: {mint}%</Text>
                <Text variant="bodyLarge">
                  Flavor Profile:{" "}
                  {type.map((item) => (
                    <Text key={item}> {item.toUpperCase()}</Text>
                  ))}
                </Text>
                <Text variant="bodyLarge">
                  Nicotine Preference: {nicotine.toUpperCase()}
                </Text>
                <Button
                  theme={{ roundness: 1 }}
                  icon="pencil"
                  mode="outlined"
                  onPress={hideDialog}
                  style={{ marginVertical: 10, marginTop: 30 }}
                >
                  Edit
                </Button>
                <Button
                  theme={{ roundness: 1 }}
                  icon="apache-kafka"
                  mode="contained"
                  onPress={genMix}
                >
                  Generate Mix
                </Button>
              </Dialog.Content>
            </Dialog>
            <Dialog
              visible={genVisible}
              theme={{ roundness: 2 }}
              dismissable={false}
            >
              <Dialog.Icon icon="leaf" />
              <Dialog.Title style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>
                Generating Mix...
              </Dialog.Title>
              <Dialog.Content>
                <ActivityIndicator
                  animating={true}
                  size={25}
                  style={{ marginTop: 10 }}
                />
              </Dialog.Content>
            </Dialog>
          </Portal>
        </Card>
      </View>
    </ScrollView>
  );
};

export default Generator;
```

I tried looking in StackOverflow if there was anyone else having this issue, but could not find a solution. Google was the same, no answers/solutions. I have tried editing the babel config and also importing reanimated and gesture handler in the main App.js file and no luck.

Answer (score 0):

After many tries, I found the issue. I added reanimated in the babel config and added `import "react-native-gesture-handler"` on top of my file instead of the App.js file. Had to restart the app and clear cache by entering "npx expo start -c" as well.